# Simple rewrite doesn't work

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I would like to access the following url:

```
http://example.com/test/?key=123
```

and get the contents of http://example.com/index.php?q=123 instead

I tried with this rules:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} key=(.*)
RewriteRule /test/.* /index.php?q=%1 [L]
```

but it doesn't work. Is there a way to make this work ?

Comment: `key=123` this is not a QUERY_STRING - it is  REQUEST_URI and QUERY_STRING is what comes after `?`

Comment: Yeah, sorry, it's actually http://example.com/test/?key=123 , but it doesn't work still...

Comment: Do you have `.htaccess` in `/test/` or in the root? Or do you put into `.conf` file?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the leading slash on `/test/.*` or replace it with a `^`, ie `test/.*` or `^test/.*`. The problem is, the leading slash is not part of the request when using `.htaccess` rewrite rules.

See the note [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteRule) under **Per-directory Rewrites**

> The removed prefix always ends with a slash, meaning the matching occurs against a string which never has a leading slash. Therefore, a Pattern with ^/ never matches in per-directory context.

I'd also clean up the query string match to use

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} key=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^test/.* /index.php?q=%1 [L]
```

Comment: I bet you meant `RewriteRule ^test/$ index.php?q=%1 [L]` instead of `RewriteRule ^test/?.* /index.php?q=%1 [L]` (which also matches `http://example.com/testanythinghere/?key=123`)

Comment: @kums probably. I'll just edit it to make the slash not optional